# AFNetworking getting HTML from rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, afnetworking

I am using AFNetworking to get JSON data from the server, but I am only getting back HTML and an error that says the following:

```
Expected content type {(
    "text/json",
    "application/json",
    "text/javascript" 
)}, got text/html, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7592470>}
```

The code is as follows:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://127.0.0.1:3000/games"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation;
operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
            success:^(NSURLRequest *req, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id jsonObject){
                                                                NSLog(@"Response: %@", jsonObject);
                                                            }
            failure:^(NSURLRequest *req, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id jsonObject){
                                                                NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                                                            }];

[operation start];
```

I am using rails and the server sends back JSON when I access the page with curl. I want to force application/json to be requested, am I doing this wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that you're sending the same parameters when you test the request with ``cURL``?

Comment: Try add .json in URL end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to tell the server what content type you want back.

Here's a common fix for this issue:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://127.0.0.1:3000/games"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
```

If this doesn't work, you'll need to step through your server code to determine under what conditions it'll return JSON instead of HTML.